# Programming language that makes the smallest executables?

Tags: windows, programming-languages, exe

I am looking for a programming language that generates the smallest EXE files.

It also needs to have no dependencies other than the DLLs that come with and are common to the following OS's: release Windows XP, Vista, 7, and 8. e.g. C++ application with static linking, Delphi, VB6, RealBasic, etc.

It should also run on all 32-bit & 64-bit Intel + AMD processors manufactured after 2000 with only one EXE.

Answer (score 7):

assembler! It can't get any smaller than that.

Comment: Depends on the coder. A modern c compiler will probably beat 99% of coders out there.

Comment: Doesn't assembler rely on the processor that it runs on? I forgot to include that it should run on all Intel + AMD processors manufactured after 2000.

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk: If I use the MSVC C++ compiler to compile C code, will it require any DLLs outside of the ones that are common to any OS post-XP?

Comment: That's a bit of an open ended question. Do you plan on dynamically linking to any files? If so, then yes, you will have to use external DLLs. If you're statically linking, then you should be just fine.

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk: Let's say that all it does is create a folder. Does that mean that it will need to link (either statically or dynamically) to the C++ libraries?

Comment: @user2327287: most assemblers will default to supporting all modern CPUs, and you can certainly configure them to support anything that will run Windows.  You don't really need to use assembler, though; see my answer.

Comment: @user2327287: that depends on *how* you create the folder.  If you use `_mkdir`, you'll need the runtime library.  If you use `CreateDirectory` you won't.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Actually, as I understand it, Windows doesn't expose a stable kernel ABI, so you at least have to link against a library sitting below the various language runtimes which serves as the forward-compatible ABI surface. (As opposed to Linux, where the design decision was for the kernel itself to provide the stable ABI.) (Source: Discussions in the rustlang issue tracker surrounding statically linking libc for self-contained binaries.)

Comment: @ssokolow, yes, `CreateDirectory` is provided by `kernel32.dll`, but that's part of Windows, not part of the runtime.  It's always there, it isn't a dependency you need to install.

Comment: @HarryJohnston True, but still a good idea to clarify it, since I've seen people get weirdly obsessive about "removing the need for DLLs" and you never know who will wander in off Google.

Answer (score 4):

This is determined by the specific build tools (the compiler and linker) that you use, and by the configuration and content, not by the language per se.

Visual C++ 2010 can generate small executables if you use plain C and exclude the C runtime library.

If you need to use the C runtime library, you might have to try using Visual C++ 6 (disadvantage: out of support) or mingw (disadvantage: generates executables which are technically unsupported) both of which use the runtime library that is built into Windows XP and later.

The executable size for Visual C++ 2010 without the runtime library is 1K for up to 512 bytes of code and initialized data.  This is as small as a working Windows executable can be, because there must be at least one section and the minimal section offset and size are both 512 bytes.

In general, the executable size will be 512 bytes of overhead plus the size of code and initialized data, rounded up to a multiple of 512 bytes.

To exclude the runtime library in Visual Studio 2010, set "Ignore All Default Libraries" to "Yes" under Linker->Input, and set an entry point (e.g., "NoCRTMain") under Linker->Advanced.  The signature of the main function in this configuration is

```
void __stdcall NoCRTMain()
```

You may also need to set "Buffer Security Check" to "No" under C/C++->Code Generation.  The buffer security check functionality uses a runtime library function.

At this point, if you have less than 512 bytes of code and constant data, the executable will be 3K in size, or 3.5K if you have initialized non-constant data.

You can save another 512 bytes by not including a manifest (Linker->Manifest File).

You can save another 512 bytes by making the image non-relocatable.  Set "Randomized Base Address" to "No" and "Fixed Base Address" to "Yes" in Linker->Advanced.

To get it down to 1K, you need to merge the code, constant data, and initialized data sections.  To do this, add these extra command-line options under Linker->Command Line:

```
 /SECTION:.text,ERW /MERGE:".rdata=.text" /MERGE:".data=.text"
```

For security reasons, you may prefer to not merge the initialized data sections; doing so partially disables Data Execution Protection (DEP).  If so, just use

```
 /MERGE:".rdata=.text"
```

or set the equivalent option in Linker->Advanced.

If you did not merge all the sections, you may be able to save another 512 bytes by replacing the default MS-DOS stub with a smaller one, reducing the overall header size to fit within the 512 bytes minimum alignment size.  This can be done by adding the /STUB command line option (Linker->Command Line) and using the [minimal stub available here](http://www.cms.waikato.ac.nz/~harry/stub.exe).  If you prefer, you can create your own minimal stub by extracting the first 64 bytes of any Windows executable.

Answer (score 2):

You will not find an answer for this. C and assembly will give you some of the smallest executables you can find but they can also give you huge executables if you're not careful.

All modern compilers make highly efficient executables.

Don't worry about it. Pick the language that gets the job done the easiest for you.

Comment: It's a proof of concept, so it's not really about getting the job done.

Comment: I really wish people wouldn't assume they know why the question is being asked.  Responses like, "Don't worry about it. Pick the language that gets the job done the easiest for you." I find to be unproductive.  It's not up to you to decide what someone else should or should not "worry about".  Answer the question if you have it, otherwise don't bother responding.