# Minimal executable file file align (MSVC 2019)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, portable-executable

I'm trying to create a small PE executable file. Everything is fine and file works well. File size is about 2kb.

However, when I try to use linker option "/FILEALIGN:16" to make the file even smaller (the final size becomes about 800 bytes), it stops working. Windows 7 gives me error "..is not a valid Win32 application", while Windows 10 tells "This app can't run on your PC".

What is wrong with file align? It is divisible by 2, even by 16.. Default file align works fine.

Comment: This seems to say the minimum is 512 but it might be possible to go lower if you also modify the section alignment. *shrug* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format

Comment: @RetiredNinja setting `SectionAlignment` and `FileAlignment` the same does make smaller executables work on newer Windows (10 or so), though that's not in the spec and won't work in older ones. https://stackoverflow.com/q/42022132