# How small can I make a clang executable?

Tags: c++, clang

I'm just testing to see how small I can make this C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "hi";
}
```

using this zsh command:

```
g++ test.cpp -Os -g -o main
```

but the smallest I can make it is 52 Kb, so is there any way to make it even smaller?

Comment: Not compiling for debug would usually remove a bunch of stuff

Comment: "small" and "-g" are in conflict.

Comment: Use `write` (assuming Linux) instead of cout

Comment: Remember that you get a chunk of the C run-time library linked into your code.  You can use `objdump` to see what your code really has in it.

Comment: You could (should!) reduce the size of the source code by removing `using namespace std;` and changing `cout` to `std::cout`.

Answer (score 6):

Using your code and compiler flags with g++ 11.2, I get a **35,8kB** executable (different result could be explained by using a different compiler version or target system).

1. Removing the `-g` flag (debugging symbols for GDB GNU Debugger or LLDB Clang/LLVM Debugger) brings the output file's size down to **16,3kB**.
2. You can modify your code without changing its functionality in the following way (**16,0kB**):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    fputs("hi", stdout);
    return 0;  // doesn't change the output, only here for completeness sake
}
```

3. Using `clang` to compile above code further reduces output executable's size to **15,9kB**.
4. Adding the `-s` flag (strip debug information): **14,5kB** (same results using both `clang` and `g++ 11.2`)

Comparison table (best results in **bold**):

| code | compiler | flags | size | step |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **original** | **g++ 8.5.0** | -Os -g | 38 496 B |  |
|  |  | -Os | 16 304 B |  |
|  |  | **-Os -s** | **14 464 B** |  |
|  | **g++ 11.2.0** | -Os -g | 35 848 B | 0 |
|  |  | -Os | 16 320 B | 1 |
|  |  | **-Os -s** | **14 464 B** |  |
|  | clang 11.0.1 | -Os -g | 30 736 B |  |
|  |  | -Os | 16 304 B |  |
|  |  | -Os -g | 14 552 B |  |
|  | clang 13.0.0 | -Os -g | 29 312 B |  |
|  |  | -Os | 16 232 B |  |
|  |  | -Os -s | 14 488 B |  |
| **modified** | **g++ 8.5.0** | -Os -g | 18 552 B |  |
|  |  | -Os | 16 000 B |  |
|  |  | **-Os -s** | **14 464 B** |  |
|  | **g++ 11.2.0** | -Os -g | 18 616 B |  |
|  |  | -Os | 16 000 B | 2 |
|  |  | **-Os -s** | **14 464 B** |  |
|  | clang 11.0.1 | -Os -g | 16 720 B |  |
|  |  | -Os | 15 960 B |  |
|  |  | -Os -s | 14 528 B |  |
|  | **clang 13.0.0** | -Os -g | 16 640 B |  |
|  |  | -Os | 15 888 B | 3 |
|  |  | **-Os -s** | **14 464 B** | 4 |

Comment: Try adding `-flto`.

Comment: You should also strip symbols if you haven't done so yet, i.e. `-s` or `-Wl,-s` or a call to `strip`.

Comment: @user17732522 I was about to post an answer just about the `-s`...

Comment: @Zakk Go ahead. I only commented instead of writing an answer myself because I am too lazy to test the results.

Comment: @user17732522 I have just noticed that the OP's explicitly compiling with clang. I have tested for GCC, so I don't think the results are relevent.

Comment: It would be nice if you organize all the results you obtained in a table: compiler, command, output size...

Comment: I'll give it a try, gimme a minute

Comment: Be aware that the process size (runtime memory usage) will be still much bigger because glibc is linked in dynamically. You can measure it with ```/usr/bin/time -v```. With a smaller libc, e.g. musl or dietlibc and ```-static```, you could get down to 0.2K, according to this bloat comparison:  http://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html

Comment: Another idea is to use ```-m32``` to build smaller 32bit binaries. x86_64 CPUs can still run this. BTW on my Ubuntu 18 system I get much smaller results (5612 B). What system do you have?

Comment: #2 defeats the C++ness of the exercise

Comment: @Spencer fair enough, but given that C++ is, for the most part, a superset of C, I considered my changes to be allowed here

Comment: @rudimeier I use Kubuntu 21.10

Comment: using all of the tips in this comment section I can only get it down to 50,808 bytes with `#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    fputs("hi", stdout);
    return 0;  // doesn't change the output, only here for completeness sake
}` and `clang++ test.cpp -Os -s -flto -o main`

Comment: sorry for the bad editing bty

Comment: Also I was looking at the hexidecimal of the executable and I found large chunks of empty space [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QCWrvuYY21CPNy76cEWYg535rTUjYyIN/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: How can I specify the compiler version? `gcc 11.2` gives a error 11.2 no such file or directory

Comment: @user16217248 maybe try `gcc-11.2`?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you should to strip symbols by "-s"

By using "-m32" you may define 32-bit code generation, which should be a bit more compact.

Finally, I suggest using the [UPX](https://github.com/upx/upx) compressor.

```
gcc -s -Os -m32 main.c
```

gcc 12.2.0 + upx = 6144 bytes win32 executable

With some additional effort you may go under 1k footprint range:

- [How to create tiny PE (Win32) executables using MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022132/how-to-create-tiny-pe-win32-executables-using-mingw)
- http://www.phreedom.org/research/tinype/
- https://keyj.emphy.de/win32-pe/
- [http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html](http://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)